# Is use of __getattribute__ for namedtuple : bad practice?

Tags: python, namedtuple, getattribute

I am exploring the  possibility of replacing very large numbers of small dictionaries with namedtuples instead.

Because dict keys (strings) have been mapped onto the field names of the namedtuples, I have to make use of the dundered getattribute method of the namedtuple to access the values.

This not only makes the code look kind of odd but I wonder also whether this is bad practice?

Comment: Almost certainly, it is *not* the right thing to do. I still don't understand why you *have* to use it. Can you show an example?

Comment: why are you looking to replace dictionaries?

Comment: @bobah it's often the case that when you have a bunch of dictionaries acting as a record, you really just want a `namedtuple`. It uses less memory and is faster, because it uses random-access without any hashing. Of course, whether this is the right way to go depends on the details.

Answer (score 3):

> Because dict keys (strings) have been mapped onto the field names of the namedtuples, I have to make use of the dundered getattribute method of the namedtuple to access the values.

That's the wrong tool. You should be using the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function, not the `__getattribute__` method:

```
getattr(your_namedtuple, attribute_name)
```

That said, if you want to primarily access your data by name instead of index, calling `getattr` all the time is going to be awkward. You could subclass your `namedtuple` class and change how `__getitem__` works so you can still use indexing notation:

```
class MyType(namedtuple(...)):
    __slots__ = () # avoid creating instance __dict__s
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(index)
        except TypeError:
            return getattr(self, index)
```